# Sqlite3 bigger equal operator date error

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to compare the dates and i'm having some problem with <= operator
My start date is "2012-07-07" and the date i want to compare is "2012-07-07" if i do this select

```
SELECT "eventos".* FROM "eventos" WHERE (start <= '2012-07-07' )
```

It dont work, but if i do

```
SELECT "eventos".* FROM "eventos" WHERE (start >= '2012-07-07' )
```

It works, the problem is the line returned has the start value as "2012-07-07"

If i just do

```
SELECT "eventos".* FROM "eventos" WHERE (start > '2012-07-07' )
```

It returns the same line with the start value as "2012-07-07"

Someone know why the sqlite3 thinks 2012-07-07 is greater than 2012-07-07?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

Just recreated the database, probably it was because i changed the type from datetime to date, now i recreated using date and recreated the records.

Thanks